# Is the Monster Group the largest finite simple group only divisible by supersingular primes?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

The Monster group has order $2^{46} · 3^{20} · 5^{9} · 7^{6} · 11^2 · 13^3 · 17 · 19 · 23 · 29 · 31 · 41 · 47 · 59 · 71 \approx 8*10^{53}$, and the primes that occur in its prime factorization are the supersingular primes.

Is there any finite simple group larger than the Monster, with a prime factorization only consisting of supersingular primes? Note the first prime not in the Monster is $37$; the largest alternating group satisfying the condition is $A_{36}$, having order around $10^{41}$, not quite there.

Comment: It seemed to me that the "easiest" way to meet the criteria would be to find a large power $2^n$ of 2 with the prime factors of $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ supersingular. But is this sort of thing excluded by the $abc$ conjecture?